# Make Eventhandler act immediately?

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

```
private void run(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
button.setDisabled(true);
Thread.sleep(3000);
button.setDisabled(false);
}
```

This is my Code.
I want to do something at the place of `Thread.sleep()` while the `Button` is disabled.
But it does everything at once.
Can somebody help?

Comment: What is "that something" that you want to execute? Should it run on a separate thread? WIll it last long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that uses a [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) on a different thread to execute the operation.

```
Button b = new Button("Button!");
b.setOnAction(e -> {
    b.setDisable(true);
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            Platform.runLater(() -> b.setText("Modified text")); // Use Platform.runLater here to modify the scene graph
            Thread.sleep(3000); 

            return null;
        }
    };

    task.setOnSucceeded(v -> {
        System.out.println("Succeed");
        b.setText("Button!");
        b.setDisable(false);
    });

    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
});
```

Comment: Using `Task` seems to be a bit overkill here... You could use `Thread`, since you do not use any of `Task`'s benefits except `onSucceeded`, which could be accomplished by a second `Platform.runLater` as well...

Comment: It really depends on the "something" from the question that should be done. Maybe the progress has to be displayed, maybe not. Without knowing the exact requirement it is difficult to provide the "best" solution (that's why I asked it in the comment firstly:)). For this stupid example I made I can agree with you.